# How to add external packages logs to current project log files/rules in Nlog

Tags: c#, .net, logging, nlog

I have some rules, that logging their projects

```
{
    "logger": "Alpha.*",
    "minLevel": "${configsetting:item=Alpha.LogLevel}",
    "ruleName": "Alpha",
    "writeTo": "fileTarget, consoleTarget"
  },
  {
    "logger": "Beta.*",
    "minLevel": "${configsetting:item=Beta.LogLevel}",
    "ruleName": "Beta",
    "writeTo": "fileTarget, consoleTarget"
  },
```

Now I add few packages to my solution (like `AB.Common.Exception`), and I want to add their logs for the log of project.

For example, if package was used by `Alpha`, log from `AB` might be added to `"ruleName": "Alpha"`, but not to `"Beta"`.

Is there any way to do this?

Regards.

**Updated**

Ok, I found possible answer with rule in end

```
{
    "logger": "Alpha.*",
    "minLevel": "${configsetting:item=Alpha.LogLevel}",
    "ruleName": "Alpha",
    "writeTo": "fileTarget, consoleTarget"
  },
  {
    "logger": "Beta.*",
    "minLevel": "${configsetting:item=Beta.LogLevel}",
    "ruleName": "Beta",
    "writeTo": "fileTarget, consoleTarget"
  },
  {
    "logger": "*",
    "minLevel": "Trace",
    "ruleName": "AB",
    "writeTo": "fileTarget, consoleTarget"
  }
```

But I want to set logLevel from `${configsetting:item=Alpha.LogLevel}` or `${configsetting:item=Beta.LogLevel}`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, my answer now looks like that

```
{
    "logger": "Alpha.*",
    "minLevel": "${configsetting:item=Alpha.LogLevel}",
    "ruleName": "Alpha",
    "writeTo": "fileTarget, consoleTarget"
  },
  {
    "logger": "Beta.*",
    "minLevel": "${configsetting:item=Beta.LogLevel}",
    "ruleName": "Beta",
    "writeTo": "fileTarget, consoleTarget"
  },
  {
    "logger": "*",
    "minLevel": "${configsetting:item=Alpha.LogLevel}",
    "ruleName": "ABtoAlpha",
    "writeTo": "fileTarget, consoleTarget"
  },
  {
    "logger": "*",
    "minLevel": "${configsetting:item=Beta.LogLevel}",
    "ruleName": "ABtoBeta",
    "writeTo": "fileTarget, consoleTarget"
  }
```

I think it's not so beautiful I hoped, but it works

**Upd**: OK, it don't work like I want - it writes all another logs only with minLevel ${configsetting:item=Alpha.LogLevel}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just need to add `"finalMinLevel": "Off"` (Introduced with NLog v5), so it doesn't reach the last catch-all-rule:

```json
"rules": [
  {
    "logger": "Alpha.*",
    "minLevel": "${configsetting:item=Alpha.LogLevel}",
    "ruleName": "Alpha",
    "writeTo": "fileTarget, consoleTarget",
    "finalMinLevel": "Off"
  },
  {
    "logger": "Beta.*",
    "minLevel": "${configsetting:item=Beta.LogLevel}",
    "ruleName": "Beta",
    "writeTo": "fileTarget, consoleTarget",
    "finalMinLevel": "Off"
  },
  {
    "logger": "*",
    "minLevel": "Trace",
    "ruleName": "AB",
    "writeTo": "fileTarget, consoleTarget"
  }
]
```

If output always should be sent to the same targets, then it can be simplied with just using `"finalMinLevel": "${configsetting:item=LogLevel}"` (Requires NLog ver. 5.1.3 or newer)

```json
"rules": [
  {
    "logger": "Alpha.*",
    "finalMinLevel": "${configsetting:item=Alpha.LogLevel:whenEmpty=Debug}"
  },
  {
    "logger": "Beta.*",
    "finalMinLevel": "${configsetting:item=Beta.LogLevel:whenEmpty=Debug}"
  },
  {
    "logger": "*",
    "minLevel": "Trace",
    "writeTo": "fileTarget, consoleTarget"
  }
]
```

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-file#rules